# how to revert transaction excuted by low level call

Tags: solidity, cpp-ethereum, solidity-0.8.x, solidity-0.5.x, solidity-0.6.x

Hello ethereum community. I'm experimenting with low level calls and i want to revert the transaction made by low level call, if i didn't get the desired result. Is it possible?

```
(bool success, ) = _contractOne.call{value: 10, gas: 100000}(payload);
        require(success);
```

let's say this is my call to swap on uniswap and i get lower output token. how to revert the transaction to initial state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to revert function if success be false.

```
(bool success, ) = _contractOne.call{value: 10, gas: 100000}(payload);

if (!success) {
    // Revert the transaction if the low-level call fails
    revert("Low-level call failed");
}

// Continue with your code if the low-level call was successful
```

Comment:  thanks bro..